# How to get individual firestore items to display on a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXowR.png)
I have an interesting bug in my code that I can`t figure out. It should be a simple React+Firestore setup, listing items on one page, and showing more details on each item on the next. Unfortunately, it only shows details for the first item on the list.
Have been digging through the Firestore documentation, where I found the following solution. It's not working...

Details

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import Servis from "./funkc/servisni";

export default function FireDetail({ match }) {
  // console.log(match);
  console.log(match.params.id);
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const getIt = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const item = [];
    const docRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("polja")
      .doc("id", "==", match.params.id);

    docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        setItem(doc.data());
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });
    setLoading(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getIt();
  }, [match]);

  if (loading) {
    return <h3>samo malo...</h3>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        Kontakt: tip - email
        <p> {item.Kontakt} </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Datum rodjenja: {item.Datum}</p>
        {item.Prezime} {item.Ime}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

List
the component that lists all of the items in the database...

```
const SORTER = {
  "Prezime A-Z": { column: "Prezime", direction: "asc" },
  "Prezime Z-A": { column: "Prezime", direction: "desc" },
  "Email A-Z": { column: "Kontakt", direction: "asc" },
};
const PAGER = {
  5: { Max: "5" },
  30: { Max: "30" },
  45: { Max: "45" },
};

export default function FireList() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("Prezime A-Z");
  const [displayMax, setDisplayMax] = useState("5");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  // function routeTo() {
  //   const { id } = useParams();
  // }

  const ref = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("polja")
    .orderBy(SORTER[sortBy].column, SORTER[sortBy].direction)
    .limitToLast(PAGER[displayMax].column);
  // console.log(ref);
  function getEm() {
    setLoading(true);
    ref.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const item = {
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        };
        items.push(item);
      });
      setItems(items);
      // console.log(items);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getEm();
  }, [query, sortBy, displayMax]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {" "}
        <label>Poredaj</label>
        <select
          value={sortBy}
          onChange={(e) => setSortBy(e.currentTarget.value)}
        >
          <option value="Prezime A-Z"> Prezime A-Z </option>
          <option value="Prezime Z-A"> Prezime Z-A </option>
          <option value="Email A-Z"> Email A-Z </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label> Max. po stranici </label>
        <select
          value={displayMax}
          onChange={(e) => setDisplayMax(e.currentTarget.value)}
        >
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </ul>
      {loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : null}

      {items.map((val) => (
        <div key={val.id}>
          <p>
            {val.Ime} {val.Prezime}
            <Link to={`/kontakt/detalji/${val.id}`}> ajd </Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

App component, providing navigation

```
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        login
        <div>
          <Header />
        </div>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Header} />
        <Route path="/adresar" component={FireList} />
        <Route path="/kontakt" exact component={ContactEdit} />
        <Route path="/kontakt/detalji/:id" component={FireDetail} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I just want to clarify, you are saying that when you click on the first `Link` in the `FireList` component you successfully see the details of the item in the `FireDetails` component but clicking on any other `Link` in `FireList` renders `FireDetail` but with no details of the object?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your Firestore so we can clone issue on our side and test it ?

Comment: Danoram - that's it.

Comment: Dharmaraj - done :)

Comment: @ydrea do you mind adding a `console.log(querySnapshot.docs.size)` and checking what it logs ?

Comment: it logs 'undefined'

Comment: from what I can tell, the problem is in the redundant 'forEach' statement... it forces the query to go over each doc, for no reason...

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read the url parameter on each render. Thath meanes useEffect( yourfunction, [match]) (avoid using [ ] as second parameter this time)

Remember, ReactRouter doesnt reload or load a page when route somwhere. All is in memory, except the first time.

Comment: but that console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); renders once ?

Comment: not even that. the console.logs show one log from line 7 (match.params.id), then one from line 19, then an empty object on line 21, then 2 more from line 7...